# Sharepoint Custom Upload Field and attachments?

Tags: sharepoint

I developed a custom sharepoint field that uploads a file in a specific document library and stores the url of the file after saqving it as the value of the field.

the problem is that the uploaded file is stored twice one in the library as I want and the other as an attachment with the item in the list that has this field.

how can I avoid savig the file as an attachment ?

thank you

**Edit:** Here's the Code:

```
public override void UpdateFieldValueInItem()
        {

            string name="";

            if(fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName!="")
            {
            //method to store the posted file in a certain library
            string x= UploadFile(this.Web, fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName,fileUploader.FileName,out name);

            //Stores The URL and the name of the file
            SPFieldUrlValue urlValue = new SPFieldUrlValue() { 
                Description=name,
                Url=x
            };

            this.Value = urlValue;
            this.ItemFieldValue = urlValue;
            }
}
```

**UploadFile method**

```
string UploadFile(SPWeb web,string path,string fileName,out string name)
        {
            UploadField uf = (UploadField)base.Field;



            SPList docsList = web.Lists[uf.StoreList];
            SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(docsList.RootFolder.UniqueId);
            byte[] contents = File.ReadAllBytes(path);


            SPFile file= folder.Files.Add(folder.Url + "/" + fileName, contents);
            //folder.Update();
            SPListItem item = docsList.Items[file.UniqueId];

            name = item["Name"].ToString();
            return getItemURL(item);

        }
```

Comment: There is no this.update() method in BaseFieldControl class methods

Comment: Ok the field inherits from SPFieldUrl  but the public override void UpdateFieldValueInItem() is in the BaseFieldControl context and this is method that the item gets updated in. the update() method of SPFieldUrl updates the properties of the field itself not the field value of the item

Comment: I have no idea what can cause problem you described. My last suggestion is that maybe your control should inherit from `UrlField` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.urlfield.aspx instead of `BaseFieldControl`.

Answer (score 0):

From the code I can see that, you are uploading to the library, but just ensure that there is no post back happening.
Again, I would suggest, you to create the link manually.
It is mostly of the form
//
Hope this helps

---

Please visit [SharePointSchool.net](http://SharePointschool.net) to get started with SharePoint 2010

Comment: How can I ensure that there is no postback. it must happen when I press the OK button